# How do I make the logged in user only see their information?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I made todo and added a note. When someone else enters, they can see my notes and not see their own notes. How can I use this and similar logic in my projects? Can you post sample code?

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

  var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  var fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              customSizedBox(),
              _customUsernameField(),
              customSizedBox(),
              _customPasswordField(),
              customSizedBox(),
              registerElevatedButton(),
      
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  SizedBox customSizedBox() => SizedBox(height: 20);
  ElevatedButton registerElevatedButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(onPressed: _register, child: const Text("register"));
  }
  ElevatedButton loginElevatedButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(onPressed: _sigIn, child: Text("login"));
  }
  dynamic _customUsernameField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: email,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return "username is not null";
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          label: Text("username"), suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_2)),
    );
  }
  dynamic _customPasswordField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: password,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return "password is not null";
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          label: Text("password"), suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.password_outlined)),
    );
  }
  Future<void> _register() async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.text, password: password.text)
          .then((value) {
        fireStore
            .collection("todo_user")
            .doc(email.text)
            .set({"username": email.text, "password": password.text});
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureBuilder and firebaseFirestore where method:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: fireStore.collection("todo_user").where("username", isEqualTo: firebaseAuth.currentUser!.email).get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[0]['username']);
          },
        )
```